# Difference between Sortby and orderby queries in Hive

Tags: hive

Hive `sort by` and `order by` commands are used to fetch data in sorted order.

For Example:

Sort by

```
hive> SELECT  E.EMP_ID FROM Employee E SORT BY E.empid;
```

Order by

```
hive> SELECT  E.EMP_ID FROM Employee E order BY E.empid;
```

What is the difference between `sort by` and `order by` queries in Hive SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hive cluster by vs order by vs sort by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715044/hive-cluster-by-vs-order-by-vs-sort-by)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hive supports SORT BY which sorts the data per reducer. The difference between "order by" and "sort by" is that the former guarantees total order in the output while the latter only guarantees ordering of the rows within a reducer. If there are more than one reducer, "sort by" may give partially ordered final results.

Note: It may be confusing as to the difference between SORT BY alone of a single column and CLUSTER BY. The difference is that CLUSTER BY partitions by the field and SORT BY if there are multiple reducers partitions randomly in order to distribute data (and load) uniformly across the reducers.

Basically, the data in each reducer will be sorted according to the order that the user specified. The following example shows

SELECT key, value FROM src SORT BY key ASC, value DESC

Answer (score 2):

`SORT BY` does not exist in typical SQL implementations. Details would presumably be found in Hive documentation, but [Gaurang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12856396/436641) indicates that `SORT BY` is per-reducer.

`ORDER BY` is in (to my knowledge) all SQL implementations. Wikipedia has [an article explaining it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by).

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing like "sortBy" in SQL

For sorting of data in SQL the `ORDER BY` clause is used which allows you to sort the records in your result set. 
And it can only be used in `SELECT` statements.

e.g.:

```
SELECT columns FROM tables WHERE predicates ORDER BY column ASC/DESC;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause sorts the result set based on the columns specified. 
`ASC` indicates ascending order.
`DESC` indicates descending order.

The default is `ASC`