# Using hive global scheduling

Tags: hive

when using hive like this:

```
 select req_time from ncsa where req_time > 90 sort by req_time limt 100;
```

you will find this：

```
958
952
951 
97
96
96
959
957
956
955 
955
953
95
94
92
```

I guess in mapps the date divided into several parts，and reduces sort by each part.

please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I do not see any problem ,please explain more clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry,it should be "select req_time from ncsa where req_time > 90 sort by req_time limt 100;" and the result is not global sort by

Comment: use group by before sort by it may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `order by` instead of `sort by`.

The difference between `order by` and `sort by` is that the former guarantees total order in the output while the latter only guarantees ordering of the rows within a reducer. see [hive docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-sortby.html) for more details.

PS. make sure `req_time` is a numeric field.

Answer (score 0):

I'll quote answer from [Hive cluster by vs order by vs sort by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715044/hive-cluster-by-vs-order-by-vs-sort-by):

- `CLUSTER BY x`: ensures each of N reducers gets non-overlapping ranges,
  then sorts by those ranges at the reducers. This gives you global
  ordering, and is the same as doing (`DISTRIBUTE BY x` and `SORT BY x`).
  You end up with N or more sorted files with non-overlapping ranges.
- So `CLUSTER BY` - is basically the more scalable version of ORDER BY.