# how to use order by with collect_set() operation in hive

Tags: sql, hive

In Table 1,  I have customer_id, item_id and item_rank (rank of item according to some sales). I want to collect a list of items for each customer_id and arrange them according to item_rank.

```
Customer_id  item_id rank_item
  23            2      3
  23            2      3
  23            4      2
  25            5      1
  25            4      2
```

The output I expect is

```
Customer_id    item_list
  23             4,2
  25             5,4
```

The code I used was

```
 SELECT
    customer_id,
    concat_ws(',',collect_list (string(item_id))) AS item_list
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    customer_id
ORDER BY
    item_rank
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use a sub-query to get a result set of (customer_id, item_id, item_rank), sorted by item_rank, and then use `collect_set` in the outer query.

**Query**

```
WITH table1 AS (
    SELECT 23 AS customer_id, 2 AS item_id, 3 AS item_rank UNION ALL
    SELECT 23 AS customer_id, 2 AS item_id, 3 AS item_rank UNION ALL
    SELECT 23 AS customer_id, 4 AS item_id, 2 AS item_rank UNION ALL
    SELECT 25 AS customer_id, 5 AS item_id, 1 AS item_rank UNION ALL
    SELECT 25 AS customer_id, 4 AS item_id, 2 AS item_rank
)
SELECT
    subquery.customer_id,
    collect_set(subquery.item_id) AS item_id_set
FROM (
    SELECT
        table1.customer_id,
        table1.item_id,
        table1.item_rank
    FROM table1
    DISTRIBUTE BY
        table1.customer_id
    SORT BY
        table1.customer_id,
        table1.item_rank
) subquery
GROUP BY
    subquery.customer_id
;
```

**Results**

```
    customer_id item_id_set
0   23  [4,2]
1   25  [5,4]
```

The sub-query uses `DISTRIBUTE BY` to guarantee that all rows for a particular `customer_id` route to the same reducer.  It then uses `SORT BY` to sort by `customer_id` and `item_rank` within each reducer.  I expect this is sufficient for the requirements, because I didn't notice a requirement for total ordering of the final result set.  (If total ordering by `customer_id` is a requirement, then I think the query would have to use `ORDER BY`, which would cause slower execution.)

Internally, the `collect_set` UDAF uses a Java [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which is an order-preserving collection, so the same sort order used in the sub-query will be maintained in the outer query's set.  This is visible in the Hive codebase here:

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/release-2.0.0/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFMkCollectionEvaluator.java#L93

Comment: Thanks Chris, but won't there be a problem with a larger data set? From what I can see Sort by or even Cluster by does not ensure Global ordering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715044/hive-cluster-by-vs-order-by-vs-sort-by

Comment: @vkaul11 , great observation!  I've updated the answer to use `DISTRIBUTE BY` and `SORT BY`.  (I didn't notice a requirement for total ordering, so I didn't use `ORDER BY`.)

Comment: No, Chris total ordering is not a requirement so indeed it suffices.

Comment: Hey folks,  I'm a few years late to the game here, but it seems that in 2022 you'll get:

`WARNING: Order/Sort by without limit in sub query or view [subquery] is removed, as it's pointless and bad for performance.`

which means that this solution is no longer viable. Any other ideas?

Comment: you can try to remove the group by all together and create an analytical function end a distinct:


SELECT distinct 
    subquery.customer_id,
    collect_set(subquery.item_id) over (partition by customer_id order by item_rank AS item_id_set
from table1.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
    customer_id,
    collect_set(item_id) AS item_list
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    customer_id
ORDER BY
    item_rank

**NOTE** : Using collect_list() gives you duplicates and collect_set() gives you unique values.