# hive subquery optimization using cluster by

Tags: sql, hive

I am joining two tables that are not bucketed. In the subquery, the data is clustered by join key. Does this help improving performance of the query compared joined without cluster by

```
select
a.user_key,b.user_key
from 
(select user_key from 
table1 
cluster by user_key) a 
left join 
(select user_key from 
table2 
cluster by user_key) b on a.user_key=b.user_key
```

Comment: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715044/hive-cluster-by-vs-order-by-vs-sort-by)

Comment: This reference doesn't answer about the performance difference of using cluster by in a sub query