# Efficiently take min of a column with other column as the key

Tags: hive, hiveql

I recently transitioned over from using Presto to Hive. I have the following scenario. Column A, B, C. I want to aggregate on A and find the value of B for which the value of C is minimized. In presto you can something like this as

`SELECT A, min_by(B, C) from <TABLE> GROUP BY A`

Now I want to do the same thing in Hive. But unfortunately I couldn't find a UDF similar to this anywhere in the documentation. Now I know I can do the following

```
SELECT A, COALESCE(B, 0)
from <TABLE> as primary
JOIN (
SELECT A, MIN(C) as C FROM <TABLE> GROUP BY A 
) secondary
ON primary.A = secondary.A AND primary.C = secondary.C\
GROUP BY A
```

I have 2 problems with this solution

1. It's not concise at all.
2. It's not efficient either. I am doing an extra subquery resulting and an extra aggregation and an extra JOIN. It would be nice to have a first class aggregation support for such a function.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do without writing your custom UDF ?

Comment: why not just sort your data and take the head instead of selecting for the min?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715044/hive-cluster-by-vs-order-by-vs-sort-by

Comment: @kpie Can you give me an example query of how would I do that ? The way I can think of is little worse than the current one.

Comment: can you post sample input so that we can work on a solution?

Comment: Hive supports standard SQL "analytic functions" (with some specificities) > manual is not usable as tutorial https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics so look for tutorials about `MIN(x) OVER (PARTITION BY a,b) AS xx` or sthg like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join works slower than analytic functions, try this approach without join, and table will be scanned only once:

```
select s.*
from
(
SELECT A, COALESCE(B, 0) as B, C,
      min(C) over (partition by A) as min_C
from <TABLE> as primary
)s
where s.C=s.min_C;
```

If you need min(C) to be calculated by more group columns, add them to the `partition BY` clause.

Comment: Great answer, but a comma is missing; here's a correction:  `select s.* from ( SELECT A, COALESCE(B, 0) as B, C, min(C) over (partition by A) as min_C from <TABLE> as primary ) s where s.C=s.min_C;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try TD_first(B,C) in hive. Works in the same fashion.